# XAMPP- Run script

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I want to run a script with XAMPP, I don't have lot of information about XAMPP and php. I download the script and put the folder into "htdocs".
also I create a database and add a user in mysql in XAMPP, and put the information in config.php. (config.php locates in my script folder that I downloaded)
I put "localhost/pslivechat/php/app.php/admin" in address box in my browser, then I enter username and password and click install. the script installed successfully. Now what should I do to run the script? In the clue of the site that I download the script, was written that: "when the installation complete put this code in body: "
what should I do now? where should I put that code? How should I run the script?
please help me

Comment: This is not a question about xampp but the script you have installed. In general, to run a script in xampp just type in your browser localhost/ followed by the name of the folder you have created in htdocs and the first file that needs to be executed.
In the informations given by you probably pslivechat must be embedded in a another site.

Comment: yes I should use this script in my site. but I don't have my own site. now I just see the management panel of the livechat in localhost. I want to test the output of this script in websites. How should I do that? when I type "http://localhost/pslivechat/" in my browser, the index o pslivechat folder is shown.

Comment: You can create another folder on htdocs and put your own site. In your site you can enter the script in the body you said in your question.